# Zygmund class, Schwartz class and Littlewood-Paley projection operators

Tags: real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, operator-theory

I'm studying Littlewood-Paley theory in harmonic analysis, where I encountered the following problem related to the Zygmund class of functions:

Consider the Zygmund class of functions defined as follows:
$$Z_C = \left\{f \in L^{\infty} \ \bigg | \ \sup_{x,h}\frac{|f(x-h)+f(x+h)-2f(x)|}{|h|} < \infty\right\}$$
Let $P_{k} \ (k \in \mathbb{Z})$ denote the Littlewood-Paley projection operators. Then we have:

(1) If $f \in Z_C$, then $\sup_{k \geq 0}(2^{k}||P_{k}f||_{L^2}) < \infty$

(2) If $f \in \mathcal{S}$ (Here $S$ denotes the Schwartz class of functions) and $\sup_{k \in \mathbb{Z}}(2^{k}||P_{k}f||_{L^2}) < \infty$, then $f \in Z_C$

I have tried investigating properties of Zygmund class of functions, but I made almost no progress...any hint/idea?

Comment: Zygmund class is the Besov space $B^1_{\infty,\infty}$. I recommend you to read the books by Triebel, e.g., Theory of Function Spaces I-II-III.

Comment: Triebel's books are nice but hard to read. I would recommend on this topic the Springer Grundlehren book Fourier Analysis and Nonlinear Partial Differential Equations by Bahouri, Chemin \& Danchin.